# Strange Xcode signing issue

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I have a strange issue in Xcode 4.3.2, I'm developing an app that uses push notifications and I setup all the things needed in the provisioning portal and in key chain. now I get to the part of signing my code and in my Xcode I don't see the profile and I don't see the small arrows in the right side of the line where I should choose the profile, instead I get this box you can see in the image I attached bellow.

[image: xCode Image]

Does anyone know something on how to solve it, because now I need to manually type in this box.

Answer (score 0):

The box is shown for `Code Signing Entitlements` and not for choosing profiles. The ones that you are looking for are right below your selected item.

Comment: All The lines are doing the same i cant get the arrows to show, only this box on all lines

Comment: Thats strange.. Have you tried restarting xcode? Sometimes it solves many problems ;).

Comment: I have deleted it and reinstall it and no change